# Как на поддомене показывать содержимое одноименной папки на основном домене?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, поддомены, mod-rewrite

Что прописать в .httaccess, чтобы при наборе адреса **subdomen.example.com** открывалась страница **example.com/subdomen**?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно иметь под домен subdomen.example.com, без него никак, а уже с него делать редирект на example.com/subdomen

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomen\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1/subdomen [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Следует уточнить у автора, нужен ли ему 301 редирект. Исходя из вопроса на данный момент это неясно, поэтому лучше убрать из ответа флаг `R=301`.

Comment: Мне нужен редирект без изменения адреса.